# Using Meteor's account methods that send emails how can I be notified of success or failure?

Tags: email, meteor

For any of the following core meteor account methods I would like to know if the attempt to send the email was a success or failure, so I can appropriately notify the client if there is an issue and no email is sent.

```
Accounts.verifyEmail
Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail
Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail
Accounts.sendVerificationEmail
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Set `Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "myemail@domain.com"`

Then your mail server should send any failed receipts back to you..

Additionally, [`Email.send`](http://docs.meteor.com/#email_send) Throws an Error on failure to contact mail server or if mail server returns an error.

Comment: Good idea, I'm also thinking about if there is an issue earlier communicating with the mail server or authentication there etc.

Comment: Updated answer with reference to docs; `Email.send` will throw an error on failure  to contact the mail server etc.